# How can I reduce the size of my git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

My git repo should be relatively small, but I committed large files in the past, so my `.git/objects/pack` file is pretty big. I haven't touched this repo in a long time, so I don't know the names of the files that are causing the repo to be much bigger in size than it needs to be.

How can I shrink the size of my git repo?

Comment: That looks pretty small for a Git index. As the index will only contain _references_ for files in the current HEAD and staged changes, large files committed in the past will have no effect on the size of your index unless they're still present in you current HEAD.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, you are correct. The large files are actually in `.git/objects` because that folder takes up 32 MB, where the rest of the repo takes up maybe 1mp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Finding and purging big files from git history](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history) is a great article on how to find and remove the big files.

The bare minimum steps are:

1) Git has a unique SHA that it associates with each object (such as files which it calls blobs) throughout it’s history. This helps us find that object and decide whether it’s worth deleting later on:

```
git rev-list --objects --all | sort -k 2 > allfileshas.txt
```

2) Get the last object SHA for all committed files and sort them in biggest to smallest order:

```
git gc && git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | egrep "^\w+ blob\W+[0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+$" | sort -k 3 -n -r > bigobjects.txt
```

3) Take that result and iterate through each line of it to find the SHA, file size in bytes, and real file name (you also need the allfileshas.txt output file from above):

```
for SHA in `cut -f 1 -d\  < bigobjects.txt`; do
echo $(grep $SHA bigobjects.txt) $(grep $SHA allfileshas.txt) | awk '{print $1,$3,$7}' >> bigtosmall.txt
done;
```

4) Use filter-branch to remove the file/directory (replace MY-BIG-DIRECTORY-OR-FILE with the path that you’d like to delete relative to the root of the git repo:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch MY-BIG-DIRECTORY-OR-FILE' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

5) Then clone the repo and make sure to not leave any hard links with:

```
git clone --no-hardlinks file:///Users/yourUser/your/full/repo/path repo-clone-name
```

5) This was not included in the article, but I needed to force-push the repo

```
git push --force
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to rewrite your Git history and remove those files: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

After that you force-push to the repo and you should be done.

I normally use `git rebase -i <options>` if a rewrite is needed but that depends on your specific circumstances.

PS: Be also aware of the implications when you do this (branches might be left without parents, other people will rebase vs hard reset so you might get those files back, etc)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I posted an answer which gave me the exact solution I needed.